# AVAudioEngine, using 3D Audio

Tags: swift, audio, core-audio, avaudioengine

I would like to use AVAudioEngine for a 3D audio effect, where the sound source circles the user head.  The source appears to move from left to right but I've been unable to figure out how to make it circle the users head.  The audio source **must** be mono or it cant work.

I dont understand AVAudioMake3DVectorOrientation and AVAudioMake3DAngularOrientation.

I thought my math was correct but I suspect that if it were, I would have gotten the results I was looking for.

This is bare bones, so there isn't much error checking.

Would someone provide guidance to get me on track?

Thank you,

W.

```
import AVFoundation
class ThreeDAudio {

var _angleIndx   = 0.0
var _engine      : AVAudioEngine!
var _player      : AVAudioPlayerNode!
var _environment : AVAudioEnvironmentNode!
var _circleTimer : Timer!

func initTimer()
{
    _circleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.10, target: self,
                                       selector: #selector(ThreeDAudio.updatePosition),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@objc func updatePosition()
{
    let centerX =  0.0
    let centerY =  0.0
    let radius  = 10.0

    let degToRads = Double.pi / 180.0
    let angle = _angleIndx * degToRads
    let x = centerX + sin(angle) * radius
    let y = centerY + cos(angle) * radius
    let z = 0.0

    let posInSpace = AVAudioMake3DPoint(Float(x), Float(y), Float(z))

    _angleIndx      += 1.0
    _player.position = posInSpace
    print("angle: \(_angleIndx) , \(posInSpace)")

    if(_angleIndx == 360.0) { _circleTimer.invalidate() }
}


func getBufferFromFileInBundle(fileName: String, fileType: String) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer?
{
    // audio MUST be a monoaural source or it cant work in 3D
    var file:AVAudioFile
    var audioBuffer : AVAudioPCMBuffer? = nil
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType)!

    do{
        file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath:path))
        audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat:(file.processingFormat), frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
        try file.read(into: audioBuffer!)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error AVAudioFile:\(error)")
    }

    return audioBuffer
}

func outputFormat() -> AVAudioFormat
{
    let outputFormat = _engine.outputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    let nChannels    = outputFormat.channelCount // testing, will always be 2 channels
    let sampleRate   = outputFormat.sampleRate
    return AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: sampleRate, channels: nChannels)
}

func setupEngine(_ audioBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer )
{
    _engine      = AVAudioEngine()
    _player      = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    _environment = AVAudioEnvironmentNode()

    _player.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTF
    _engine.attach(_player)
    _engine.attach(_environment)

    _engine.connect(_player, to: _environment, format: audioBuffer.format)
    _engine.connect(_environment, to: _engine.outputNode, format: outputFormat())

    _environment.listenerPosition = AVAudioMake3DPoint(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    _environment.listenerVectorOrientation = AVAudioMake3DVectorOrientation(AVAudioMake3DVector(0, 0, -1), AVAudioMake3DVector(0, 0, 0))
    _environment.listenerAngularOrientation = AVAudioMake3DAngularOrientation(0.0,0.0, 0.0)


    do{
        try _engine.start()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error start:\(error)")
    }   
}

func startAudioTest()
{
    var thisFile = (name: "", fileType: "")
    thisFile = (name: "sound_voices", fileType: "wav")
    thisFile = (name: "Bouncing-Ball-MONO", fileType: "aiff")

    let audioBuffer = getBufferFromFileInBundle(fileName: thisFile.name, fileType: thisFile.fileType )
    if ( audioBuffer != nil )
    {
        setupEngine( audioBuffer! )
        initTimer()
        _player.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer!, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)
        _player.play()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: At first sight, your code looks correct to me. Are you certain that the audio doesn't move in a circle and that you just don't hear it? Depending on the HRTF which is used by the audio renderer, you might get more or less spectacular effects. You could try to check the output signal in Matlab or some equivalent and see if the audio segment which is supposed to be in the front is exactly the same as the one supposed to be in the back.

Comment: I changed the radius based on your comment, thinking that you may have the answer.  If the sound were a lot closer in radius, I might be able to distinguish the effect but unfortunately there was no change.  I tried spherical head algorithm as well but that didnt make it better.